# Preciso de ajuda para definir um comando IF

Tags: javascript, classes, tampermonkey

As vezes ao enrar uma página que eu uso aparece um alerta de erro na primeira opção, então tenho que clickar na opção 2, então gostaria de definir um comando IF,para que quando aparecesse o alerta de erro, o script clickasse na segunda opção, porém não sei configurar o if. O código do erro é esse:

```
<div role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" class="error flash__message"><div class="flash__message-content">You have too low respect to enter this place< data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="alertClose" class="flash__close-button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button></div>
```

E meu script é esse:

```
setInterval(function enter() {
var entrar1 = document.getElementsByClassName('pull-right')[5];
var entrar2 = document.getElementsByClassName('pull-right')[7];
if (AQUI VAI O COMANDO DO ERRO,PORÉM NÃO SEI COLOCAR") {
    entrar2.click();
} else {
    entrar1.click();
}
},1000);
```

OBS: Estou usando tampermonkey para automatizar o script.

Comment: No caso eu só queria definir o IF caso aquele alerta apareça

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o elemento existe na página com:

```
if( document.querySelectorAll("div.error.flash__message").length ){
   // existe
}else{
   // não existe
}
```

O `document.querySelectorAll("div.error.flash__message").length` irá contar quantas div's possuem as duas classes `.error` e `.flash__message`. Se existir pelo menos uma div na página com as duas classes, o `if` será atendido.

Comment: valeu, funcionou !!

Comment: Não deixe de marcar a resposta como certa